# How to store the coordinates from a mapbox geocoder search?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Im trying to add a circle around a location after you search on mapbox. The built-in mapbox geocoder doesn't let you handle the response by default and I can't find any documentation on how to do this. I was hoping to add the search result to a useState or UseEffect to make a circle (and delete the old one) every time a search is made.

Below is my code for now but I can only add the circle on load and not dynamically.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl, { Map } from "mapbox-gl";
import MapboxGeocoder from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import { point, circle } from "@turf/turf";

function MapBox() {

    const mapContainerRef = useRef(null);

    const [lng, setLng] = useState(-90);
    const [lat, setLat] = useState(45);
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(6);

    // Initialize map when component mounts
    useEffect(() => {
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainerRef.current,
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
            center: [lng, lat],
            zoom: zoom,
        });

        // Add navigation control (the +/- zoom buttons)
        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");
        map.addControl(
            new MapboxGeocoder({
                accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
                mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
            }),
        );

        map.on("load", () => {
            let center = point([lng, lat]);
            let radius = 220;
            let options = {
                steps: 80,  // number of sides of circle
                units: "miles", // unit for radius
            };
            let pinkCircle = circle(center, radius, options);

            map.addLayer({
                "id": "circle-fill",
                "type": "fill",
                "source": {
                    "type": "geojson",
                    "data": pinkCircle,
                },
                "paint": {
                    "fill-color": "pink",
                    "fill-opacity": 0.5,
                },
            });
        });

        map.on("move", () => {
            setLng(map.getCenter().lng.toFixed(4));
            setLat(map.getCenter().lat.toFixed(4));
            setZoom(map.getZoom().toFixed(2));
        });

        // Clean up on unmount
        return () => map.remove();
    }, []); 

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="sidebarStyle">
                <div>
                    Longitude: {lng} | Latitude: {lat} | Zoom: {zoom}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="map-container" ref={mapContainerRef} />
        </div>
    );
};


export default MapBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results by subscribing to events.

```
let geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
        })

geocoder.on("results", function(results){
    // You will get here all the results from your input query
}

geocoder.on("result", function(result) {
    // You will get the result of location that was selected from the drop-down.
}
map.addControl(geocoder, "top-left")
```

Docs : https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/main/API.md#on

So, in your use-case you can subscribe to the "result" event and change state based on the event, which will help you to draw a circle dynamically. The response will also give you bounding box coordinates and center coordinates.